# Update table data in angular 6 site without refreshing state when data update in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I am developing angular 6 site. it's fetching data from firebase firestore and display on table.
But if site is already load and I have fetch data and display on table after that If I delete or update record in firebase directly then Can I get that immediate reflection on web table

Is it possible with observable of angular firebase like AngularFirestore ?

Answer (score 0):

Your client needs event to act on, it cannot be automatically without event to trigger, you can use some scheduler or maybe with **setTimeout** to pull the data and refresh your table, if you have control on that external site you can push notification from it to your server side, then trigger that from your client to get the data refreshed.

Comment: I want something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q3VOhcOJjM&feature=youtu.be but `FirebaseListObservable` not available in @angular/fire. Have you any idea to replace FirebaseListObservable in angular 6